# In Python, does this expression "(a is b) == ( id(a) == id(b) )" always return True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, object-identity

In Python, the expression `(a is b) == ( id(a) == id(b) )` appears to always returns True, where `a` and `b` are variables referring to some object, since the `id` function returns the memory where they are stored and `is` is used for object identity.

Are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 3):

```
(a is b) == ( id(a) == id(b) )
```

This expression is always `True`.
There are two possible ways:
1. Both `a` and `b` refer to the same object

```
>>>a='Hello'
>>>b=a
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a)==id(b)
True
```

2. Both 'a' and 'b' refer different objects.

```
>>>a='hello'
>>>b='world'
>>>a is b
False
>>>id(a)==id(b)
False
```

`id(a)==id(b)` does what `a is b`  does.

Now, Incase1 `(a is b) == ( id(a) == id(b) )` this is `True==True` which returns `True`.
In second case `(a is b) == ( id(a) == id(b) )` this is `False==False` which returns `True`

From [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for an object’s identity: *x is y* is true if and only if *x* and *y* are the same object. An Object’s identity is determined using the `id()` function. *x* is not *y* yields the inverse truth value.

Comment: You only demonstrated that it is the case for two strings, not that it is always the case.

Comment: @nnnmmm Can you show a case where `a is b == (id(a)==id(b))` returns `False`? For which datatype this doesn't hold `True`

Comment: No, I think it's true that they're always the same, but the answer doesn't explain that. You could link to an authoritative source instead that explains e.g. that the `is` operator is implemented via comparison of object addresses.

Comment: @nnnmmm I exactly answered that. `a is b` is `True` only when `a` and `b` are referring to the same object. And `id(a)==id(b)` is True` only when `a` and `b` are referring to the same object. That was the reason for a downvote? I don't understand what more I have to explain. The question was not about how `is` is implemented.

Comment: @nnnmmm [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) Also say the same. Moreover the question about why that expression always evaluates to `True` and not about how `is` or `id` is implemented. I don't really understand the reason you downvoted? ;)

Comment: @nnnmmm [`id()` is defined as the "identity" tag of an object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), and [`is` is an identity check](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not), they match by specification and by definition.

Comment: The answer mentioned that but didn't provide any sources for that assertion. Thanks for editing the answer, removed the downvote.

Comment: @nnnmmm Always open for suggestions and improvements. We collectively improved the answer for the community. `;)`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `is` only to compare to `None`, which I believe you should, then the question is irrelevant as `None` has a well-defined address

```
>>> id(None)
10306432
>>> id(None)
10306432
>>> a = None
>>> id(a)
10306432
```

I have yet to encounter a situation where `a is b` yields a result different from `id(a) == id(b)`, but you still don't want to use `is` carelessly :

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> id(a), id(b), id(1)
(10914496, 10914496, 10914496)

# 1 has a single address, is fails to recognize that a and b were created separately.

>>> a = 500
>>> b = 500
>>> id(a), id(b), id(500)
(140251806972464, 140251806973200, 140251806973744)

# Unlike the previous case, 500 is created multiple times, each with a different address

>>> a, b = 500, 500
>>> id(a), id(b), id(500)
(140251806972336, 140251806972336, 140251806972464)

# Several instances during the same initialization are created with a single address

>>> a, b = 500, 5*100
>>> id(a), id(b), id(500)
(140251806973104, 140251806973200, 140251806971280)

# However it only works if all are created in the same manner...

>>> a, b = 5*100, 5*100
>>> id(a), id(b), id(500)
(140251806971920, 140251806973392, 140251806973104)

# ... and they have to be created explicitely.


>>> a = 500 ; b = 500
>>> id(a), id(b), id(500)
(140251806973104, 140251806973104, 140251806972464)

# Separating with a semicolon does not change this fact...

>>> 500 is 500
True
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = 500
>>> a is 500
False
>>> a = 500 ; a is 500
True

# However being in the same line is not a basis for always having the same address, even if all values were created explicitly :

>>> any([a is 500 for a in [500]])
False
```

Other objects each have their own erratic behavior :

```
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> b = 'hello'
>>> id(a), id(b), id('hello')
(140251789045408, 140251789045408, 140251789045408)

>>> a = 'hello' + ' '
>>> b = 'hello' + ' '
>>> id(a), id(b), id('hello' + ' ')
(140251789044344, 140251789012472, 140251789012920)

>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> id(a), id(b), id([])
(140251789066632, 140251789069704, 140251789174216)
```

I would conclude that the behaviors of `is` and `id` are too unreliable for `(a is b) == (id(a) == id(b))` to be useful **even if it were true**, at least in the case of immutable objects.

I personally would never think of using `is` in any case other than

```
if x is None:
    pass
```

and I reserve `id` for only mutable objects or custom classes.